# PHP PDO: method to recognize automatically if a INSERT or UPDATE

Tags: php, sql, methods, pdo

im making a class to easy manage SQL commands. I created all CRUD and right now im trying make a new method called save ($ data, $ table).
"save" must Recognize if INSERT or UPDATE is a sentence.

I'm totally lost in this step, my brain does not sense a safe and effective way to recognize which of the two sentences is.

My first idea was to compare using the primary key ...

value exists : update

value doesnt exists or empty : insert

But,this is a weak solution.For example, if a malicious user sends ID=5 in form, automatically overwrite the user with id 5.

I accept suggestions and solutions, Thanks!

Comment: `if a malicious user sends ID=5 in form, automatically overwrite the user with id 5` sanitize form data.

Comment: Or, you know, just prepare your statements. One might note that PDO happens to be well-known for parametrized queries.

Comment: What type of SQL?  MSSQL?  MYSQL?  POSTGRESQL?

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan Isn't the idea behind using PDO to abstract away the particulars of the database?

Comment: @arxanas The connection, yes, but not the SQL you're using.  There can be be query breaking syntactical differences between the languages.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan You have me there, but I imagine most forms of SQL implement `UPDATE` and `INSERT` more or less the same.

Comment: @Stefan  I think you're asking two different questions:  First, how do I recognize whether to insert or update data, and Second:  how do I keep malicious users from updating data?  The important thing about seeing them as separate questions is that they have separate answers.  The first is a question about SQL, the second: user authentication.  Which do you want us to answer here?

Comment: @arxanas - More information never hurt anyone.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan sorry for the delay in response, I had no internet connection... Robbie just answered my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two parts to the answer:

1. the SQL you want is

   INSERT(fields) VALUES() ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...
2. the method to control is to send some other unique identifier, not the ID. In your table, have the primary key (auto increment) and also a "unique_id" random string md5()'d set as unique key in the table. Send the random string as the identifier. Then do the update based on that random string. If it doesn't exist, it'll create a new record and auto-increment a primary key.

I would go deeper than this to validate if you're expecting a "new" or "update", but this method appears to fit what you're asking for.